# ZK framework advice grails

Tags: grails, zk

I am needing something to allow a user to use a tool to define a layout which then can be applied to a grails application.

I have been looking into ZK Framework, It seems this will allow it but I am not 100% sure.
Has any one made use of this before?

Or could anyone suggest any alternative.

Comment: Do you mean the user create a zul page, and it be applied to your view?

Comment: yes exactly that, so the zui pages can be interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the [ZKGrails](https://code.google.com/p/zkgrails/) plugin does what you want.

It enables you to port the ZUL pages you developed in ZK to Grails. In particular, you would extend the class `GrailsComposer` (which in turn extends from ZK's `GenericForwardComposer`) in order to autowire your ZUL UI components to Grails event handlers.

This [ZKGrails tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/zkgrails/wiki/LoadOnDemandZKGrails2) shows how to port the [ZK's Load-On-Demand program](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2008/June/Use_Load-On-Demand_to_Handle_Huge_Data) to Grails.